# How to position text on bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` where I want to set a text on bottom. How can I do this using HTML and CSS?

**CSS**

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  display: block; 
  background-color: red; 
  height: 15%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<header>
  <font size="28.5" color="#2D6A17" face="Colonna MT" margin-top="5px">
    <%=id%>
  </font>
</header>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *top to bottom*

Comment: Your question is very confusing, could you make it more concise?

Comment: <font> tag is depricated.

Comment: when i set text it is showing on the top of herder i  want it on  desired position

Comment: Maybe provide an image of what you desire? do you want to write top to bottom like in chinese?

Comment: Show an image of how your result should look like for easy understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start putting your HTML code within the standards:

```html
<header>
   <div class="id"><%=id%></div>
</header>
```

How can you see, I removed the `font` because it was deprecated. But we can use CSS to style your element:

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
  color: #2a6a17;
  display: block;
  font: normal 28.5pt 'Colonna MT'; 
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It's unable to set a percentage for `height` in this case, for this reason I change the value to `150px`.

There is two ways to do it:

## positioning

First of all, you'll need to add `position: relative;` on header.

```css
header {
  ...
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

So, now it's simple, you need set `position` and `bottom` properties on `.id` element:

```css
header .id {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**The Result:**

[image: The Result]

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/caio/k7w5W/.

## table

Here you'll need to change the `display` to `table` and set the `width` to `100%`.

```css
header {
  ...
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Now, after put `display: table-cell;` on `.id` you'll able to use `vertical-align` properties:

```css
header .id {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**The Result:**

[image: The Result]

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/caio/M4RVh/.

Comment: how to set text on desired position

Comment: @user3585120 where is your "desired position" for the text?

Answer (score -2):

First:

In  your example the correct HTML and style should be like below:

```
header
{ font-family:Colonna MT;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#2D6A17;
text-align:center;
display:block; background-color:red;
 height:15%;
 margin-top:5px;
}


<header>  <p>  test  </p>   </header>
```

Second:

If you want to adjust the p tag, you can set the width and height  or set up a position for it .